# Valid JSON in Response

Tags: json, api, http, rest

I am working on a client and server application and came across an interesting problem.  We are creating a restful API and communicating to the clients with JSON responses.  When doing a DELETE, we are returning a 200 OK with a blank response.  Our clients are getting the 200 OK, but failing on parsing the JSON.

We completely understand the failed parse (there is nothing to parse), but we had a bigger question.  Is sending a blank response valid JSON, or should we be returning `{}` or something to that effect?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [HTTP/1.1 definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) concerning the DELETE method:

> A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an
>   entity describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action has not yet
>   been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been enacted but
>   the response does not include an entity.

So if your server is deleting the item immediately, then the suggested responses would be:

- 200 OK - return some kind of status code (like a boolean true, or a string saying "success")
- 204 No Content - return nothing, and have your client look out for this response and not attempt JSON parsing, while still knowing the request was successful

Comment: Re: whether a blank response is "valid JSON" - The definition at [json.org](http://json.org/) says a JSON value can be "a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array".  So, unless there's some philosophical difference between "valid JSON" and "a valid JSON value", then I would say a blank response is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 7):

Just doing a quick test here: http://jsonlint.com/ reveals that a blank is not valid JSON, while `{}` is valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, I have seen JSON parsers like that and on clients.  The question I want to know is if a blank response is a valid JSON (in the HTTP/JSON protocol sense) or just cannot be parsed.