# How to return HTTP 204 response on successful DELETE with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm having problems returning a HTTP 204 with no body using ServiceStack

If I return:

```
return new HttpResult() {
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent 
};
```

The first time it works perfectly, but a repeated call will cause Fiddler to throw an error stating last response wasn't formed properly. I believe it is because the content type is not explicitly set to `application/json`, and the response comes back with an empty string or single space character.

Setting `ContentType = "json"` on the `HttpResult` object for some reason returns a HTTP 405 response. (which is a side curiosity - not my primary concern)

If I return void, then the response is an HTTP 200, which I am using currently, but I'd like to think I could provide the preferred 204 response.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a simple response filter to set a `No Content` header on the response if there is no response.

Set the filter in the `AppHost` `Configure` method:

```cs
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, obj) => {
    // Handle void responses
    if(obj == null && res.StatusCode == 200)
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        res.StatusDescription = "No Content";
    }
});
```

Then when a method returns `void` the correct header will be set.

```cs
public void Delete(TestRequest request)
{
    // I don't return anything
}
```

Regarding your `405` error response for JSON. This will only occur if you send an empty response and a status `200`, as this is malformed JSON. But sending the above `204 No Content` will prevent this error. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971627/1295344).

Comment: Hi Scott, that looks good. Wondering... have you came across circumstances where non-success responses are returned without body and hence incorrectly transformed?  Maybe a 403 is returned without a body? (or some other response I haven't thought of)

Comment: @richardwhatever My ServiceStack applications always throw an exception when an error occurs in the method, and these exceptions always have a suitable explanation response, so it doesn't go through this filter, nor would the response be `null`. But if you have that concern, then a simple check of the original status will do, before preparing the `No Content` response. An empty JSON response is not considered malformed with an error status code. `res.StatusCode == 200` check added to code.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do something along these lines

```
public void Delete(FooRequest request) {
    // Perform deletion

    base.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
}
```

I like this approach instead of the global response filter since this allows me to have all logic pertaining to this request in the same place instead of having to remember what response filters I have.